# Phone number reading through string fails when run in full code

Tags: c, scanf, gets

I just wrote a C program  to read the name ,age and phone number from the user,store them in variables and display them back.While name and age is working perfectly but its not in case of phone number. if i run the phone number code only it works just perfectly but when done with other 2 it just don't ask for input .

**WHOLE PROGRAM CODE**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, age;
    char phone[10];
    char name[100];
    printf("ENTER YOUR NAME:");
    gets(name);
    printf("ENTER YOUR AGE:");
    scanf("%d",&age);
    printf("ENTER YOUR PHONE NUMBER:");
    gets(phone);

    puts(name);
    printf("%d",age);
    puts(phone);


}
```

**WHILE JUST THE PHONE NUMBER CODE WORKS PERFECTLY**

```
    #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

char phone[10];
    printf("ENTER YOUR PHONE NUMBER:");
    gets(phone);
    puts(phone);
}
```

Comment: I guess it is the classic input bug: scanf left a newline in the input stream so your gets just reads the newline. I think this question pops up on SO at leat once a day

Comment: OT: Don't use `gets`

Comment: Use `fgets` instead of `gets` and instead of `scanf`. Then use `sscanf` for integer parsing.